# Javascript delete operator on array list element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am confused about delete operator use on array element.

I found that delete can be used with array elements and it removes the element but doesn't update array length , so basically that element is replaced with undefined.But when i tested it I found that it replaces it with blank.

```
var test = new Array()
delete test[id];
```

So i have 3 points regarding this

1. `test[id]` id in this is element or index of element, as I read that id can be both. But when I tested it , I found its working only when i pass index.
2. What if the array has no element and I try to delete by passing any value like `delete test[3]`?
3. when i delete an element then it replaces that with undefined or blank?

Comment: The delete operator removes a property from an **object**. -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes I tried it finally and I am updating the question

Comment: `[]` is better than using `new Array()` to create new Array

Answer (score 4):

Don't use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) on array, use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

1. `delete` will not remove the element actually from array. It'll just set the value to `undefined`
2. `delete` does not alter the `length` of array

**`delete` Demo**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

delete arr[2];

document.write(arr);
console.log(arr);
document.write('<br />Length: ' + arr.length);
```

Use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

`splice()` will return silently, if you passed an out of bound index to remove.

```
arr.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
```

**`splice()` Demo**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.splice(2, 1);
arr.splice(100, 1); // For out of bounds index, it fails silently

document.write(arr);
console.log(arr);
document.write('<br />Length: ' + arr.length);
```